# If else not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a small issue with jquery code below.The first if segment of the code is working fine but the else part is not working.

```
function show_table() {
        var table_name = '<?php echo $table_name; ?>';
        if(table_name = "users" ) {
            $("#users").css('display', 'block');
        }else if(table_name = "questions") {
            $("#questions").css('display', 'block');

        }
    }


  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#block").click(function() {
            show_table();
            return false;
        });
    });

<a id="block" class="btn btn-info fa fa-cog" href=""></a>

<div style="display: none;" id="questions">
   <p>Questions</p>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="users">
   <p>users</p>
</div>
```

Can any one please help me solve this issue.

Comment: table_name = "questions" to table_name == "questions"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error must be because you are assigning the variable table_name with the string "users" rather than checking weather equal to it, in the if condition. i.e, you have a small typo error at the if condition statement `if(table_name = "users" )`
in the third line of your code.

change it like `if(table_name == "users" )` and the code is bound to work.

not only on the third line's if condition, its repeated regularly in the if condition. replace the `=` with `==` in all the if conditions.

hope this helps and the code works.. :)

Comment: Thnx how could i do that :)

Comment: search for `if(` and check weather if its a = or a ==. There are very less possibilities of an assignment inside an if.

Answer (score 4):

Use `==` NOT `=` in the `if` and `else if` condition , using `=` will always result `true` and so the `if` condition will always be executed unless the assign is to a `0` or `NaN` or `undefined` or other [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

Comment: hey what's wrong in your explanation that OP didn't accept this ??

Answer (score 3):

Use `==` instead of `=`. The former is a comparison, while the latter is an assignment.

```
    if (table_name == "users" ) {
        $("#users").css('display', 'block');
    } else if(table_name == "questions") {
        $("#questions").css('display', 'block');
    }
```

Read more in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).